# Dereference operator on temporary object

Tags: c++, destructor, temporary-objects, full-expression

In a code like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A {
    int i;

    A() {
        std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl;
    }
};

void f(const A& a) {
    std::cout << "f(A)" << std::endl;
}

std::unique_ptr<A> make_a() {
    return std::make_unique<A>();
}

int main() {
    f(*make_a());
}
```

Is there a guarantee that the `A` object will be deleted only after `f()` was executed?

Comment: wow 5 answers in 30 seconds

Comment: @Amadeus: We're on fire today. Mine was first. I congratulated myself on that.

Comment: @Bathsheba all are correct +1 to all :D

Comment: @Amadeus: Early Chrismas this year!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a guarantee that the A object will be deleted only after f() was executed?

The C++ standard guarantees that all temporary objects live till then end of evaluating of the *full expression* (the one that ends with a semi-colon `;`). See [Lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) for full details:

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created, and if multiple temporary objects were created, they are destroyed in the order opposite to the order of creation. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's guaranteed that the [temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) will be destroyed after the full-expression, which includes the invocation of the function `f()`.

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created, and if multiple temporary objects were created, they are destroyed in the order opposite to the order of creation. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception.

Answer (score 4):

Yes that's correct. The C++ standard states clearly that all anonymous temporaries passed as function parameters survive the function call.

Answer (score 4):

The object will be deleted after evaluation of the full expression `f(*make_a());`

Answer (score 4):

Temporary objects are destructed once the *full expression* they're involved in ends.

In your case the *full expression* is `f(*make_a())`, which means that the object will be destructed once the call to `f` is finished (after the function `f` have returned).